# Linq with Dynamics CRM, how to handle null ? Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dynamics-crm, dynamics-365

the join query given below gives error

> (Object reference not set to an instance of an object)

it happen when there is no record returned by join:

```
 Contact party =
                   (from c in crmContext.pp_configurationSet
                    join p in crmContext.ContactSet
                    on c.pp_name equals p.FullName
                    where c.pp_name == "DeletedBy" &&
                    c.StateCode == pp_configurationState.Active
                    select p).FirstOrDefault().ToEntity<Contact>();
```

I just have check if I do not use .`FirstOrDefault` and `ToEntity` it do not throws error.

I need to return "`Contact`" from query. Can someone guide me on how to handle null check?

Answer (score 0):

On Linq query, if you used `FirstOrDefault` which rturns the first element of a sequence, or a default value (The default value for reference and nullable types is null) if the sequence contains no elements. You can read about it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx).

Over the result of `FirstOrDefault` you are invoking `ToEntity` method. If the result is null, the application will throw `NullReferenceException` (Object reference not set to an instance of an object). This is an **expected** flow.

Now to handle `Null` Check, either you can update `ToEntity` method if it's owned by you (it's not a linq method from System.Linq namespace) or write a new extension which should handle null and convert to `ToEntity` if result is not null.

Answer (score 0):

[`FirstOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) returns null if there is no records found. This is what is causing the `NullReferenceException` on the `ToEntity` call.

You could expand this to two lines so you can do a null check, like so:

```
var party = (from c in crmContext.pp_configurationSet
                join p in crmContext.ContactSet
                on c.pp_name equals p.FullName
                where c.pp_name == "DeletedBy" &&
                c.StateCode == pp_configurationState.Active
                select p).FirstOrDefault();
if (party != null)
{
    Contact contact = party.ToEntity<Contact>();
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a [null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) and [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator) operator for extra C# points:

```
Contact party = (from c in crmContext.pp_configurationSet
                join p in crmContext.ContactSet
                on c.pp_name equals p.FullName
                where c.pp_name == "DeletedBy" &&
                c.StateCode == pp_configurationState.Active
                select p).FirstOrDefault()?.ToEntity<Contact>() ?? new Contact();
```

Comment: Tried var party = (from c in crmContext.pp_configurationSet
                join p in crmContext.ContactSet
                on c.pp_name equals p.FullName
                where c.pp_name == "DeletedBy" &&
                c.StateCode == pp_configurationState.Active
                select p).FirstOrDefault();  

Same error

Comment: Tried var party = (from c in crmContext.pp_configurationSet
                join p in crmContext.ContactSet
                on c.pp_name equals p.FullName
                where c.pp_name == "DeletedBy" &&
                c.StateCode == pp_configurationState.Active
it says party is not null, I tried :
if (party != null)
                {
                    Contact contact = party.FirstOrDefault().ToEntity<Contact>();
                }

Same error again :(

Comment: @hussmom check your other references are not null: `crmContext` and `pp_configurationState`

Comment: Used use a null-conditional and null-coalescing  same error :(

Comment: they are not null.

Comment: @hussmom in that case I'm not sure what is null just by looking at it, you will need to use the debugger and investigate further to see what is causing it.